# Check when is the next schedule running Laravel

Tags: laravel

There is any way to see when the next `schedule` command is going to run?

Example:

```php
$schedule->command("update:example")->dailyAt('07:00')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Now it's `2020-09-23 08:00:00` and the next timestamp the schedule will run is supposed to be `2020-09-24 07:00:00`.

There is a way to get that `2020-09-24 07:00:00` before it actually happens?

---

I just found articles about logs, and that's not what I want.

Comment: from where do you want to check the next scheduled task?

Comment: @lagbox anywhere, if there's a way to see it...

Comment: I think I wasn't clear on my question, sorry, I don't want to compare schedules between themselves. I want to get when a specific command is going to run again.

Comment: alright I think I have what you were looking for, answered below, good luck `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the tasks and spin through them to find what you need

```
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$schedule = app(Schedule::class);

$tasks = collect($schedule->events());

$matches = $tasks->filter(function ($item) {
    return Str::contains($item->command, 'update:example');
});

// assuming you get something back in that collection

$matches->first()->nextRunDate();
```

You should get some type of Carbon object back with what you need.

Hope that helps you out.